# Create a summary Pandas DataFrame using concat/append via a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Can't get my mind around this...

I read a bunch of spreadsheets, do a bunch of calculations and then want to create a summary DF from each set of calculations. I can create the initial df but don't know how to control my loops so that I

1. create the initial DF (1st time though the loop)
2. If it has been created append the next DF (last two rows) for each additional tab.

I just can't wrap my head how to create the right nested loop so that once the 1st one is done the subsequent ones get appended?

My current code looks like: (which just dumbly prints each tab's results separately rather than create a new consolidated sumdf with just the last 2 rows of each tabs' results..

```
#make summary
area_tabs=['5','12']
for area_tabs in area_tabs:
    actdf,aname = get_data(area_tabs)
    lastq,fcast_yr,projections,yrahead,aname,actdf,merged2,mergederrs,montdist,ols_test,mergedfcst=do_projections(actdf)
    sumdf=merged2[-2:]
    sumdf['name']= aname #<<< I'll be doing a few more calculations here as well 
    print sumdf
```

Still a newb learning basic python loop techniques :-(

Comment: I would recommend do_projections returning a named tuple or dictionary, there is scope for a typo here if you mis-order a variable name.

Comment: Thanks.. one step at a time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a neater way than writing for loops, especially if you are planning on using the result, is to use a list comprehension over a function:

```
def get_sumdf(area_tab):  # perhaps you can name better?
    actdf,aname = get_data(area_tab)
    lastq,fcast_yr,projections,yrahead,aname,actdf,merged2,mergederrs,montdist,ols_test,mergedfcst=do_projections(actdf)
    sumdf=merged2[-2:]
    sumdf['name']= aname #<<< I'll be doing a few more calculations here as well 
    return sumdf

[get_sumdf(area_tab) for area_tab in areas_tabs]
```

and concat:

```
pd.concat([get_sumdf(area_tab) for area_tab in areas_tabs])
```

or you can also use a generator expression:

```
pd.concat(get_sumdf(area_tab) for area_tab in areas_tabs)
```

.

To explain my comment re named tuples and dictionaries, I think this line is difficult to read and ripe for bugs:

```
lastq,fcast_yr,projections,yrahead,aname,actdf,merged2,mergederrs,montdist,ols_test,mergedfcst=do_projections(actdf)
```

A trick is to have `do_projections` return a named tuple, rather than a tuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Projection = namedtuple('Projection', ['lastq', 'fcast_yr', 'projections', 'yrahead', 'aname', 'actdf', 'merged2', 'mergederrs', 'montdist', 'ols_test', 'mergedfcst'])
```

then inside **`do_projections`**:

```
 return (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)  # don't do this
 return Projection(1, 2, 3, 4, ...)  # do this
 return Projection(last_q=last_q, fcast_yr=f_cast_yr, ...)  # or this
```

I think this avoids bugs and is a lot cleaner, especially to access the results later.

```
projections = do_projections(actdf)
projections.aname
```

Comment: For completeness in your code you have areas_tabs that needs to be area_tabs (no extra 's')

Comment: @dartdog thanks, I also spotted a potential issue with the original (which namedtuple solves) where you overwrite the aname variable - usually good idea to use `_` if you're planning on discarding that variable :).

Answer (score 1):

Do the initialisation outside the for loop. Something like this:

```
#make summary
area_tabs=['5','12']

if not area_tabs:
    return # nothing to do

# init the first frame
actdf,aname = get_data(area_tabs[0])
lastq,fcast_yr,projections,yrahead,aname,actdf,merged2,mergederrs,montdist,ols_test,mergedfcst =do_projections(actdf)
sumdf=merged2[-2:]
sumdf['name']= aname

for area_tabs in area_tabs[1:]:
    actdf,aname = get_data(area_tabs)
    lastq,fcast_yr,projections,yrahead,aname,actdf,merged2,mergederrs,montdist,ols_test,mergedfcst =do_projections(actdf)
    sumdf=merged2[-2:]
    sumdf['name']= aname #<<< I'll be doing a few more calculations here as well 
    print sumdf
```

You can further improve the code by putting the common steps into a function.

Comment: Thanks that shows the basic idea I need, I just could not think it through right!

Comment: But Andy's approach is more 'pythonic'!

Comment: @dartdog totally agree